# Lunr backed client side search module

Tags: javascript, api, prototypal-class-design

I created a client side search module. Could anyone please provide review pointers on it?

```
var search = function(){

"use strict";

var _instanceMap = {};
var maxLimit = 50; //TODO: add a perf test to determine the scale.

/**
 * @constructor
 * @private
 */
function _IndexCreator(_searchConfig){
  this.ref = _searchConfig.ref;
  this.id = _searchConfig.id;
  this.fieldsConfig = _searchConfig.fieldsConfig;
  this.refToDocumentMap = {};
}

/**
 * Creates an index with the document and the config
 */
_IndexCreator.prototype.createIndex = function(){
    var me = this;
    var _idx =  lunr(function(){
        this.ref(me.ref);
        if(!me.fieldsConfig){
            return;
        }
        var idx = this;
        for(var key in me.fieldsConfig){
            if(key && me.fieldsConfig[key]){
                idx.field(key,me.fieldsConfig[key]);
            } else {
                idx.field(key);
            }
        }
    });
    this.idx = _idx;
    return _idx;
};

/**
 * Searches the index for the document
 * @params {object} document - The document to be searched
 */
_IndexCreator.prototype.search =  function(docToBeSearched){
    var me = this;
    var results = this.idx.search(docToBeSearched).map(function(result){
        return me.refToDocumentMap[result.ref];
    });
    return results;
};

return {
      /**
       * Creates and index and pushes it to the instanceMap
       * @params {object} documents - documents to be indexed
       * @params {object} searchConfig - config object to create an index.
       * @example
       * {id:"",
          ref:"",
          fieldsConfig:{
            'tags':{boost:1},
            'widgetId'
            },
          limit:1
          } - contains the searchable keys of a document, id of the document,id of the instance and the limit 
          of the documents which can be indexed
       * @params {string} ref - refers to the id of the documents indexed
       * @params {string} id - refers to the id of the index created
       */
    createInstance: function(documents, searchConfig){
        var instance, refToDocumentMap = {},
          limit = searchConfig.limit || maxLimit;
        if(searchConfig === undefined || searchConfig.id === undefined){
            console.log("Invalid configuration passed");
            return;
        } 
        if(_instanceMap[searchConfig.id] === undefined){
            instance = new _IndexCreator(searchConfig); 
            var index = instance.createIndex();
            var numDocsIndexed = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                var refId = searchConfig.ref;
                var docToBeIndexed = documents[i];
                if(refId !== undefined){
                    var docRefId = docToBeIndexed[refId];
                    if(numDocsIndexed <= limit && refToDocumentMap[docRefId] === undefined){
                        index.add(docToBeIndexed);
                        refToDocumentMap[docRefId] = docToBeIndexed;
                        numDocsIndexed++;
                    }
                }
            }
            _instanceMap[searchConfig.id] = instance;
            instance.refToDocumentMap = refToDocumentMap;
        } 
        return _instanceMap[searchConfig.id];
    }, 
    /**
    * Returns the instance of the index based on the id passed
    * @paramas {string} ref - id of the index passed.
    */
    getInstance: function(id){
        return _instanceMap[id];
    },
    /**
    * Updates the index referenced by the id with the document(s)
    * @paramas {Array/Object} documents - Documents to be updated, can be either an array of documents
    * or a document
    * @params {string} id - id of the index to update the document with
    */
    update: function(documents, id){
        if(_instanceMap[id] === undefined){
            console.log("No index found for the id");
            return;
        }
        var idxInstance = _instanceMap[id];
        if(Array.isArray(documents)){
            for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++){
                var refId = document[i].refId,
                    refDocMap = idxInstance.idx.refToDocumentMap;
            refDocMap[refId] = documents[i];
            idxInstance.idx.update(documents[i]);
          }
        } else{
            idxInstance.idx.update(documents);
            var refId = documents.refId,
                refDocMap = idxInstance.idx.refToDocumentMap;
            refDocMap[refId] = documents;
            idxInstance.idx.update(documents[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's a few points to consider:

- The module gets plugged into a separate module management framework.
- Need pointers on update being an API while the search being defined as a prototype method. My reasoning was search being a stateless method while update changes the state of the method.
- `getInstance` exposes a possibility of Law of Demeter violation by the client. Any thoughts on that?
- Any input on developing a debug extension for this and the parameter check would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full code review, and my comments might be off base if you based your naming on the API you are using. The naming confuses me. I cannot read this code and know what it does without really focusing, that's not how code should read.

For `_IndexCreator`:

- `ref` <- ref to what ?
- `fieldsConfig` <- since there is no other config, I would call it simpy `config`
- `refToDocumentMap` <-What is a documentMap, and why would you say here what the ref is about but not in `ref` ?

Also in these comments:

```
   * @params {string} ref - refers to the id of the documents indexed
   * @params {string} id - refers to the id of the index created
```

I would go for

```
   * @params {string} doc(ument)sID  - refers to the id of the documents indexed
   * @params {string} indexId - refers to the id of the index created
```

For this:

```
_IndexCreator.prototype.createIndex = function(){
    var me = this;
    var _idx =  lunr(function(){
        this.ref(me.ref);
        if(!me.fieldsConfig){
            return;
        }
        var idx = this;
        for(var key in me.fieldsConfig){
            if(key && me.fieldsConfig[key]){
                idx.field(key,me.fieldsConfig[key]);
            } else {
                idx.field(key);
            }
        }
    });
    this.idx = _idx;
    return _idx;
};
```

- You do not need `_idx`, you could assign straight to `idx` instead
- The check for `key` in your loop is not needed.
- I am not sure, to be tested, but you should be able to always call `idx.field(key,me.fieldsConfig[key]);` unless you really need that second parameter to be `undefined`.
- I would create `key` as a var up front
- You only need to assign `this` to something for closures, otherwise I would advise to stick to `this`, it helps the reader
- I would assign `me.fieldsConfig[key]` to a shortcut variable for easier reading

Something like this:

```
_IndexCreator.prototype.createIndex = function(){
    var me = this;
    this.idx =  lunr(function(){
        var key, value;
        if(!me.fieldsConfig){
            return;
        }
        this.ref(me.ref);
        for(key in me.fieldsConfig){
            value = me.fieldsConfig[key];
            if( value  ){
                this.field(key, value);
            } else {
                this.field(key);
            }
        }
    });
    return this.idx;
};
```

For function `update`, there is a clear case of copy pasting of this :

```
        idxInstance.idx.update(documents);
        var refId = documents.refId,
            refDocMap = idxInstance.idx.refToDocumentMap;
        refDocMap[refId] = documents;
        idxInstance.idx.update(documents[i]); <--- Hmmmm?
    }
```

Except that now you seem to have a bug potentially, since `i` is either `undefined` or some random global variable. Create a function with the proper 4 lines and call it either in a loop or not. Actually, my preferred approach for the *how to deal with something that could be an array?* is turning a not-array into an array and then just deal with arrays:

```
update: function(documents, id){
    if(_instanceMap[id] === undefined){
        console.log("No index found for the id");
        return;
    }
    var idxInstance = _instanceMap[id];
    //Turn that documents into an array!
    if(!Array.isArray(documents)){
        documents = [documents];
    }
    //Normal processing
    for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++){
        var refId = document[i].refId,
            refDocMap = idxInstance.idx.refToDocumentMap;
        refDocMap[refId] = documents[i];
        idxInstance.idx.update(documents[i]);
    }
}
```